# DOM, удалить дочерний узел

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Надо добавлять и удалять узлы в `div`. Добавлять могу а удалять нет. Пишет это не родитель.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

var cloneInp;

function iff() {
  cloneInp = inputs[2].cloneNode(true);
  inputs[2].after(cloneInp)
}

function remov() {
  inputs.removeChild(inputs[0]);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="First" value="First Name">
  <input type="text" name="Last" value="Last Name">
  <div class="phones">
    <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="Telephone"><br>
    <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="Telephone">
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Add">
</form>
```

Comment: Опиши более подробно, что именно и от куда ты хочешь удалить, если честно, то по коду не понять...

Comment: А вам узлы не всей формы надо а только те что внутри div?

Answer (score 0):

С одной стороны вы берете элементы формы по индексу. Таким образом перебираются все функциональные элементы формы input, кнопки и тд. А с другой стороны они не все являются прямыми детьми `DOM` формы. Потому что у вас там внутри формы `div`, а в нём 2 вложенных `input`.

Поэтому нужно удалять узлы, определив сначала их 'DOM' родителя. `inputs[0].parentElement.removeChild(inputs[0]);` Ну либо сделайте формы без вложенных `div`.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

var cloneInp;

function iff() {
  cloneInp = inputs[2].cloneNode(true);
  inputs[2].after(cloneInp)
}

function remov() {
  inputs[0].parentElement.removeChild(inputs[0]);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="First" value="First Name">
  <input type="text" name="Last" value="Last Name">
  <div class="phones">
    <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="Telephone"><br>
    <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="Telephone">
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Add" disabled>
</form>
<br/>
<button onClick="iff();">Дублировать третий узел</button>
<button onClick="remov();">Удалить первый узел</button>
```

Если вам надо работать с элементами внутри div, то тогда вот такой пример.

```js
var mydiv = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var cloneInp;

function iff() {
  elem=mydiv.getElementsByTagName('*')[2];
  if (elem!=undefined) {
    cloneInp = elem.cloneNode(true);
    elem.after(cloneInp)
  }
}

function remov() {
  elem=mydiv.getElementsByTagName('*')[0];
  if (elem!=undefined) {
    mydiv.removeChild(elem);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form><!--
  --><input type="text" name="First" value="First Name"><!--
  --><input type="text" name="Last" value="Last Name"><!--
  --><div class="phones"><!--
  --><input type="text" name="Telephone1" value="Telephone"><!--
  --><input type="text" name="Telephone2" value="Telephone2"><!--
  --><input type="text" name="Telephone3" value="Telephone3"><!--
  --></div><!--
  --><br><!--
  --><input type="submit" name="" value="Add" disabled><!--
--></form>
<br/>
<button onClick="iff();">Дублировать третий узел</button>
<button onClick="remov();">Удалить первый узел</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Узлы можно удалять очень просто, используя функцию [Node.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```
var el = document.getElementById("id1");
el.remove();
```

Родителя извлекать и знать не обязательно.